# FFMPEG How to remove cover art/attatchment

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to **remove a cover** from a file while encoding. I was using `-map_metadata -1` but this doesn't work.

This is my ffmpeg command: xxxx and input/output are real values

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v -map 0:a:0? -map 0:s? -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx265 -b:v xxxxk -preset superfast -vf "scale=1920:-2" -c:a copy -c:s copy -x265-params pass=1 -f Matroska -y NUL && ^
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v -map 0:a:0? -map 0:s? -map_metadata -1 -c:v libx265 -b:v xxxxk -preset superfast -vf "scale=1920:-2" -c:a copy -c:s copy -x265-params pass=2 output
```

ffmpeg is sees the cover as a video: (looks **exactly** the same without `-map_metadata -1`)

```
Stream #0:4: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 
             640x360 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
```

The mapping looks like this: (looks **exactly** the same without `-map_metadata -1`)

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:1 (mjpeg (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (eac3 (native) -> ac3 (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:4 (copy)
```

1. Which command should I use to remove this completely (also with other files with more than one audio stream)
2. Is it possible to copy it the "right" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-map 0:V` in place of `-map 0:v` to not map cover streams.

To copy cover streams but encode regular video streams, keep `-map 0:v` and change `-c:v libx265` to `-c:v copy -c:V libx265` and `-vf "scale=1920:-2"` to `-filter:v:0 "scale=1920:-2"`

Comment: Thanks mate works like acharm :-)